# How to access value of nested dictionary with only subkey?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, python-itertools

I have the following nested dictionaries:

```
{
  "category": "string",
  "top_bottom": {
    "count": 0,
    "data": [
      {
        "store_name": "string",
        "store_id": "string",
        "value": 0
      }
    ],
    "end_name": "string"
  }
}
```

And I want to get the value for the key `store_name`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll always need to know the "full path" to get there. So if your dictionary is called `myDict`, for instance, you'd get there with

```
myDict["top_bottom"]["data"][0]["store_name"]
```

If you have no way of knowing the "full path," it may be a good idea to consider a different structure for your data.